# How can i check storage size by each folder in EFS?

Tags: amazon-efs

In EFS directory, I have folder structure like below

```
project/A
       /B
       /C
```

...

I want to monitor each folder storage size every day.
ex) A folder size => 500 GB, B folder size => 200GB

How can i do this efficiently?

Can i see the information in AWS console??

Answer (score 0):

The best option I found is:

```bash
du -h --max-depth=1
```

Note: the `--max-depth=1` make it faster

also, you can use `ncdu` it takes time to index them all but it give an excellent navigation option...